# Receiving JSON data but nothing is being printed (Swift)?

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I'm trying get data from [this](https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/fiats) API, currently have a function to test if I'm receiving any data and it is printing nothing. I get no error message though so I must be getting some data right? I'm using the same functions to parse JSON in another file for different API and that is working so no idea what I'm doing wrong.

This is a struct for the API:

```
struct Currency: Codable {
    let name: String
    let rate: Double
    let symbol: String

}
```

This is parsing the JSON from the API, storing it in array and printing it (to test it is working).

```
// Arrays to store our currency JSON data
    var currencies = [String]()

@objc func fetchJSON() {
        // API for Currency data
        let urlString = "https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/fiats"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {           // If URL is valid
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {  // Create a Data object and return the contents of the URL
                // We're OK to parse!
                parse(json: data)
                return
            }
        }
        // Show Error if failed
        performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(showError), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
    }

    func parse(json: Data) {
        // Creates an instance of JSONDecoder, which is dedicated to converting between JSON and Codable objects.
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        // Call the decode() method on that decoder, asking it to convert our json data into a Cryptocurrencies object.
        if let jsonFiat = try? decoder.decode(Currency.self, from: json) {
            currencies = [jsonFiat.name]
            test()
        } else {
            performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(showError), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
        }
    }

    func test(){
     print(currencies)
    }
```

Comment: I've used that same for function for another API call though? Its taught in HackingWithSwift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode to an array and then map that array

```
if let jsonFiat = try? decoder.decode([Currency].self, from: json) {
    currencies = jsonFiat.map { $0.name }
    test()
}
```

---

Below is my test code from my playground

```
struct Currency: Codable {
    let name: String
    let rate: Double
    let symbol: String
}

var currencies = [String]()

func fetchJSON() {
    let urlString = "https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/fiats"        
    if let url = URL(string: urlString), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {  // Create a Data object and return the contents of the URL
        // We're OK to parse!
        parse(json: data)
        return        
    } else {
        print("Download failed")
    }
}

func parse(json: Data) {
    print(json)
    // Creates an instance of JSONDecoder, which is dedicated to converting between JSON and Codable objects.
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    // Call the decode() method on that decoder, asking it to convert our json data into a Cryptocurrencies object.
    if let jsonFiat = try? decoder.decode([Currency].self, from: json) {
         currencies = jsonFiat.map { $0.name }
        test()
    } else {
        print("decode failed")
    }
}

func test(){
    print(currencies)
}

fetchJSON()
```

Comment: Nothing is printed still

Comment: @George I took your code and ran it in my playground and it works fine. (I had to remove the `performSelector` stuff and the `@objc` first)

Comment: Apologies! Somehow deleted my call function line, stupid me. Yeah its working. Now I can actually access data and I can work on using it now. Thanks :)